# exclude Jest snapshots from git whitespace check

Tags: git, whitespace, githooks, jestjs

I am trimming whitespace from git commits using `git diff-index --check --cached HEAD --`.  I want to add Jest tests using snapshots, but the snapshot files include whitespace and my tests will always fail if I remove it.  So I want to exclude the `*.js.snap` files from the whitespace check.  How do I tell git to exclude `*.js.snap` (or, alternatively, `**/__snapshots/*`) files from `git diff-index`?  I'm using bash on OSX.

In the meantime, I'm working around the problem by changing my commit hook to be interactive:

```
# If there are whitespace errors, print the offending file names and fail.
git diff-index --check --cached HEAD --
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # Allows us to read user input below, assigns stdin to keyboard
    exec < /dev/tty

    while true; do
        echo "Your commit introduces trailing whitespace.  Are you sure you want to commit? y/n"
        read yn
        case $yn in
            y ) exit 0;;
            n ) exit 1;;
        esac
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Git does have a way of specifying paths to exclude, though it's poorly documented and apparently not very well known.  It's known as [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual.html#def_pathspec), and in this case can be used as follows:

```
git diff-index --check --cached HEAD -- ':!*.js.snap' .
```

where `:` is the special character that specifies that the pathspec is not just a regular path, and '!' specifies that files matching the rest of the path should be excluded from the list of matches.

Not as straightforward as Mercurial's `-X` or `--exclude`, but it's there.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19257975/6309), the path argument of [`git diff-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index) is of  glob-style pattern, interpreted by the shell.

So this is more a shell issue than a git command problem.

See for instance "[How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216995/6309)"

You can either try and activate `shopt extglob`, or (simpler), do a post-step to your script, looking (with `git status`) for any modified files with `**/__snapshots/*` in their full pathname, and cancelling their modification (git checkout).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I spent quite a lot of time playing with negative wildcards and GLOBIGNORE, but neither would work.  Both only seemed to work with patterns that don't include more than one wildcard (`**/*`).

Comment: I'll still award you the bounty since I can't give it to myself, not that you are concerned with reputation at this point!

Comment: @undefined Thank you for this feedback, and +1 to your answer. I mentioned pathspec before here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38931091/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/35622183/6309, with examples in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33462321/6309